# Cannot get to populate subdocument using virtuals

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to populate two subdocuments using virtuals. I am using Nestjs decorator, but the syntax is pretty clear to understand. Here are my schemas:

```
@Schema()
export class FieldModel {
  @Prop({ enum: CrfFieldType, required: true })
  fieldType: CrfFieldType;

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  uuid: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  fieldName: string;
}

@Schema()
export class CrfScheduleItemModel {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  uuid: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  visitName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  screening: boolean;
}
```

And here the schema containing the virtuals which I want to populate:

```
@Schema({
  _id: false,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
class CrfFieldReadingModel {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  fieldName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: MongooseSchema.Types.Mixed })
  fieldValue: any;
}

export const CrfFieldReadingSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(CrfFieldReadingModel);

CrfFieldReadingSchema.virtual('field', {
  ref: 'FieldModel',
  localField: 'fieldName',
  foreignField: 'fieldName',
});

@Schema({
  _id: false,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
class CrfReadingModel {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: String })
  visitId: string;

  @Prop(raw({ uuid: String, email: String }))
  user: User;

  @Prop(raw({ uuid: String, date: Date }))
  encounter: {
    uuid: UniqueId;
    date: Date;
  };

  @Prop(raw({ uuid: String, date: String }))
  site: {
    uuid: UniqueId;
    name: string;
  };

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: Laterality })
  laterality: Laterality;

  @Prop([{ required: true, type: CrfFieldReadingModel }])
  values: CrfFieldReadingModel[];

  @Prop({ default: '' })
  notes: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  createdOn: Date;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  updatedOn: Date;
}

export const CrfReadingSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(CrfReadingModel);

CrfReadingSchema.virtual('visit', {
  ref: 'CrfScheduleItemModel',
  localField: 'visitId',
  foreignField: 'uuid',
});

@Schema({
  collection: 'crf',
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
export class CrfModel {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  trialId: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: String, ref: 'TrialConfigModel' })
  trial: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, index: true })
  patientId: string;

  @Prop([{ type: CrfReadingModel, required: true, default: [] }])
  readings: CrfReadingModel[];
}

export const CrfSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(CrfModel);
```

When doing `CrfModel .find() .populate('readings.visitId') .populate('readings.values.fieldName`)

I am not getting any of the desired fields populated. Just something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63adbd8a30884136b0dbb740",
        "patientId": "daa6381b-659c-41d0-abce-41dfe2573bb9",
        "trialId": "c02edc03-158f-4654-acd0-c2071f3fd8b5",
        "__v": 0,
        "readings": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "uuid": "5fb1264b-b38f-4a39-888e-91af0a4c866f",
                    "email": "reader1@igmail.com"
                },
                "visitId": "c14f9e47-53e2-4ab2-a92d-4fd4f87bb603",
                "laterality": "OS",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "fieldName": "CST",
                        "fieldValue": -1
                    }
                ],
                "notes": "",
                "createdOn": "2022-12-29T16:17:14.505Z",
                "updatedOn": "2022-12-29T16:17:14.505Z"
            }
        ],
        "id": "63adbd8a30884136b0dbb740"
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, in my case the problem was on the query. When you populate, you should use the virtual field name, not the one from the field you want to populate from.

In this case it would be `CrfModel .find() .populate('visit') .populate('readings.values.fieldName`

`visit` instead of `readings.visitId`